# Looking for a  "web-scraping script builder" 

Tags: java, screen-scraping, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm writing the code to access and download data from some web sites using **HTMLUnit**.

**I was wondering whether a tool that could help me exists**. I think maybe to a visual tool, something that lets you express the path you want to follow on the web sites visually and generates the Java code.

I'd like something for HTMLUnit, but I'm open to other solutions.

Writing screen-scraping code gets very repetitive :(

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind are [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) and maybe [ifttt](http://ifttt.com/wtf) – but both are standalone proprietary products, not tooling for HTMLUnit.

Comment: changed subject to a more general one, after your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work at [screen-scraper](http://screen-scraper.com/).  Not sure if it's quite what you're looking for, but it's definitely a powerful tool for building web-scraping scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly visual tools, but maybe you could use something like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) for recording navigation scripts of web pages. They surely are easier to use than writing all the input requests by hand in HTMLUnit.

Comment: these are interesting solutions, even though I haven't understood whether the two tools can be used as an API for running the generated scripts from an application you create

Answer (score 1):

There is only one tool that does exactly this - and does it very very well - but it's highly expensive, since their technology is amazing. Some of the biggest companies uses this. I think you might be able to get a free trail, if you want to try it out. http://kapowsoftware.com/

Comment: this is the nearest thing to what I had in mind, even though I hoped something free could exist :-)